# Update a $scope object from run function in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have my notification listener in the run function. When a notification is received I need to update a object present in $scope with a parameter present in notification object.

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'chatsCtrl'])
.run(function($state, $ionicPlatform) {
  window.FirebasePlugin.onNotificationOpen(function(notification) {
    // Need to append this notification.parameter to a scope variable present in a controller  
  }
}
.controller('chatsCtrl', function($scope) {
  // $scope.chats
});
```

How can I go about doing this? I don't want to use $rootScope object as $scope.chat object will get very heavy.

Thanks

Comment: try using `$broadcast`  https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/

Answer (score 1):

you can't call `scope` variables/functions inside run block. since you don't want to use `rootscope` my suggestion is to create a service and assign values to a particular method in that service from the run block. Then get that value from the controller using the same service.

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'chatsCtrl'])
.run(function($state, $ionicPlatform) {
  window.FirebasePlugin.onNotificationOpen(function(notification) {
     sampleService.setData(notification)
  }
}
.controller('chatsCtrl', function($scope,sampleService) {
   $scope.chats =  sampleService.getData()
});
.factory('sampleService', function() {
   var data;
   return {
     getData : function(){ return data},
     setData: function(param){ data = param},
   }
});
```

Comment: here `$broadcast` may be a better way

Comment: yeah but try to avoid listeners like `broadcast` as much as possible. it will reduce the performance and increase the complexity

Comment: @sachilaranawaka I implemented what you suggested. But the data was not persisting. So I had to store it in localStorage till I retrieved it in the controller. Or does the factory persist data?

Comment: @Pradeep Rajashekar if you are not overriding the get method again data should be persistent